# Questions where someone actually went out of their way to provide an answer?

Tags: discussion

I just bountied https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67340/4188 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/30181/4188 and I intend to do so with any other similar answer because I want to encourage where people do not merely share their knowledge (which is great) but actually go and do something for the sole purpose of answering a question. What else do we have?

Comment: Great idea! Also, this is *definitely* something we should be more competitive about - who'll be the first to literally climb a mountain to answer a question? `:-D`

Comment: So tweeting the consulate or airline, for example? If you search "Tweeted" you may find a few of mine ;)

Comment: No, I meant an IRL action. I asked airlines on Facebook, email etc too.

Comment: Well, it is already working; I have read both the accepted/bountied answers and have +1'd them.  I am totally up for doing the same against my questions.  Great idea.